# stack of void pointer calling it's function

Tags: c++

```
stack<void*> g_stack;
bool stack_push(void (*Function)())
{
    if (Function != nullptr)
    {
        g_stack.push(Function);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void stack_pop(void)
{
    g_stack.pop();
}

bool stack_process(void)
{

        if (g_stack.top() == nullptr)
            return false;

    
        void *f = g_stack.top();
        
        return true;
}

void Func1() { cout << "1" << std::endl; stack_pop();  }
```

I'm pushing some function pointers on the stack
I want to get the top and call that function
I'm pushing for example Func1() on the stack
void *f = g_stack.top();
how do I call it ?

Comment: Probably `void (*f)() = g_stack.top(); f();` (With `stack<void (*)()> g_stack;`).

Comment: Or `auto f = g_stack.top(); f();`, or `g_stack.top()();`

Comment: Why are you testing for `nullptr` twice? This code typically belongs in a class, `g_stack` would be private, and a class invariant would be that there are no nullpointers on the stack.